# Bootstrap class functionality

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to Bootstraps.  What does the bg-3 or bg-4 class do?  I'm quite confused on this class.

Here is the code

```
bg-4
```

Comment: which version of bootstrap are you using?

Answer (score 1):

They're not Bootstrap classes. They are just normal classes, which appear i.e. in [W3Schools tutorials](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_theme_me.asp), but like in [this example](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_theme_me_containers), styles are defined in code and they're not from Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you are using it but as far as I know it is in bootstrap 4 alpha versions. Hopefully they don't change it in the stable version.

I'd suggest you to go for the earlier stable version of bootstrap.

If you still want to know about it, I found a [link](http://basscss.com/v7/docs/background-colors/). This may help you out.